# jQuery: move window viewport to show freshly toggled element

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show, scrollto

I have a snippet of jQuery in doc ready which toggles a div containing a `textarea`:

```
$('div#addnote-area').hide(); // hide the div
$('a#addnote-link').click(function() { // click event listener on link
     $('div#addnote-area').toggle(); // toggle the hidden div 
});
```

The toggle works fine when clicking the link. The problem I'm having is that if `div#addnote-area` is below the browser's current viewport, it remains there when it's shown. I'd like the user's cursor to go to the textarea and for the whole textarea to be viewable in the window.

[image: Click here to see an image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [scrollTo jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).  You can simply do something like this:

```
$.scrollTo('div#addnote-area');
```

Or, if you want to animate it, provide the # of milliseconds for the scrolling to last:

```
$.scrollTo('div#addnote-area', 500);
```

Comment: @Matt Thanks, that does the trick! Wish there was a simple jQuery (non-plugin) way, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 54):

*Without* the scrollTo plugin

```
$(window).scrollTop($('div#addnote-area').offset().top)
```

**EDIT:** Well I sure get a lot of points from this old answer :)

Here's a bonus, this can also be animated.

Just use the `animate()` function and target the body tag:

`$('body').animate({scrollTop:$('div#addnote-area').offset().top},500)`

Try it on Stackoverflow! Open the inspector console and run

`$('body').animate({scrollTop:$('#footer').offset().top},500)`

Comment: The animated solution seems to work for Chrome and not Firefox (18.0.1).  I am not too sharp with JS/jQuery, anyone know why this may be?

Comment: Try to animate both body and html..`$('body,html')`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `scrollTop` also works. Try setting like:

```
 $('#idOfElement').css('scrollTop', 10)
```

You can get height/width pretty easily using `$(...).offset()`.